# How to plot multiple gauge plots from a dataframe by using e_charts?

Tags: r, gauge, echarts4r

I was trying to plot multiple gauge plots from a dataframe at once as below:

```
df<-data.frame("group"=c("A","B","C"), "value"=c(57, 23, 65))

df|>
e_charts() |>
  e_gauge(df$value, df$group
  ) |>
  e_facet(rows = 1, cols=3)
```

However, the figure showed as below, instead of having 3 gauge plots in a row:
[image]

I would like to know how to plot it in a right way. Thanks very much for your time.